# execute code just before exit while

Tags: arduino

Does anyone know how can I do to before exit the while perform a specific code? (only before leaving the while).
I can't use else because it makes the code sequence doesn't work properly

```
EDIT:

Currently I have three screens:
1. Home screen
2. flow different 0
3. configurations

The software starts from the home screen;
If the flow != 0 it performs the screen 2;
If flow is back to 0 the display returns to screen 1;
If I'm on the screen 1 and press a button it goes to screen 3;

The problem is that if I execute the function immediately after the while I will never go to the screen 3.
```

Thanks a lot.

PS: I'm using C and Arduino.

```
while (flow != 0){
  Serial.print("running flow");
  // It does some things...
  // Performs an action only before leaving the while
}
```

---

```
void loop_lcd(){
  loop_flow();
  if (flow != 0){
    update_time();
    set_state(2);        
  }    
  else{     
    switch(state){
      case 1: // SCREEN 1
      Serial.println("screen 1");
        switch(check_button()){
          case (bLEFT):
            Serial.println("LEFT button pressed");
            lcd.clear(); set_state(3);
            break;
          case (bRIGHT):
            Serial.println("RIGHT button pressed");
            lcd.clear(); set_state(3);
            break;          
          default:
            set_state(1);  
        }
        break; 
      case 3: // SCREEN 3
        Serial.println("executando tela 3");
        // ............
        // CODE
        // ............
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}
void set_state(char index) {
  state = index;
  switch(state){ 
    case 1: // STATE 1
      //LINE 1
      lcd.setCursor(2, 1); 
      print_day_and_time();
      break;
    case 2: // STATE 2
      // LINE 0
      lcd.setCursor(2, 0);
      print_day_and_time(); 
      // LINE 1
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      print_time();
      // ............
      // CODE
      // ............   
    case 3: // STATE 3
      // screen 3
      // ............
      // CODE
      // ............  
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: And where is your problem with this?

Comment: Why do you want to do it before leaving the while? Is there any difference of executing your specific code just after the while?

Comment: Do you mean `break`? Your question is very unclear. Does `// It does some things...` modify `flow`?

Comment: The problem is that I can not perform this function only if the flow is equal to 0.
If you run the function shortly after the while it will not perform other functions below.

Comment: No, it doesn't change the flow. I tried to edit and explain my situation better.

Comment: Please show the code (maybe simplified?). I still do not understand the problem and I strongly believe, that there is no problem

Comment: Here it is. It is a little messy because I had to take a part. It is quite large. Thanks

Comment: I dont find the while loop in this code, how is it related to the question?

Comment: Sorry, that was the last code. I am trying with many different ways and ended up not changing here. But did you get what I want to do? I'm trying to solve this problem in any possible way. I appreciate if you have any suggestions

Comment: I still do not understand at all what is the problem. In the code you show there is no "flow". Please read about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You might read my answer and comment why it does not help you.

Comment: the third line has "flow". I will try to solve my problem. Thank you @tobi303!

Comment: there is a varaible called "flow", but what I meant is: In the code you show there is no "flow of the program" because you do not show where is the loop or how `loop_lcd()` is called

Comment: The code is huge. Tomorrow try to post my problem in a simplified way. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but one way would be this:

```
while (flow != 0){
  Serial.print("running flow");
  // It does some things...
  if (flow == 0) { foo(); }
}
```

but I would **not do this** and actually to me your question sounds like you are looking for a solution where there is no problem. Simply do this:

```
while (flow != 0){
  Serial.print("running flow");
  // It does some things...
}
foo();
```

if you want `foo()` to be executed after the while has stopped running.